# KineticJS and mouseover and opacity

Tags: kineticjs, mouseover, opacity

I created a JSFiddle located here:

jsfiddle.net/r17k48bp/

I can't seem to figure out why the mouseover event doesn't change
the opacity but clicking on the group does??

Thanks,

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to redraw layer after shapes updating.

```
mgroup.on('mouseover', function() {
 this.opacity(0.5);
 shapesLayer.draw();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r17k48bp/2/